# How to prove function continuous on a point?

Tags: matrices, continuity

Prove that if $f:(a,b) \longrightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ is defined at $c$, $a < c < b$, and $f(c^+) = f(c) = f(c^-)$, then $f$ is continuous at $c$.

It feels like use squeeze theorem for $f$ at point $c$. But I have no idea how.

Comment: What definition of continuity are you using? One of the standard definitions is precisely what you are asked to show.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** a simple $\epsilon / \delta$ thing...

details:

Let $\epsilon > 0$.

As $\lim_{c^+} f = f(c)$: there is $\delta>0$ such as 
$$
c<x<c+\delta \implies |f(x)-f(c)|\le \epsilon
$$

As $\lim_{c^-} f = f(c)$: there is $\delta'>0$ such as 
$$
c>x>c-\delta' \implies |f(x)-f(c)|\le \epsilon
$$

Then if $|x-c|\le \min(\delta,\delta')$:

$$
|f(x)-f(c)|\le \epsilon
$$

hence $$\lim_c f= f(c)$$